# CKAN-Datastore: Bad request - Action name not known: datastore_search"

Tags: ckan

I installed the CKAN from source for Ubuntu 18.04. 
To set up the DataStore in CKAN I followed this documentation in https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html. So the problem is with setting the permissions.

I tried the following command to set the permissions:

```
paster --plugin=ckan datastore set-permissions -c /etc/ckan/default/development.ini | sudo -u postgres psql --set ON_ERROR_STOP=1
```

As output:

```
You are now connected to database "datastore_default" as user "postgres".
REVOKE
REVOKE
GRANT
GRANT
GRANT
GRANT
REVOKE
GRANT
GRANT
GRANT
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
CREATE VIEW
ALTER VIEW
GRANT
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
DO
```

I am irritated by "You are now connected to database "datastore_default" as user "postgres"
In my development.ini I have following settings:

```
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://ckan_default:pass@localhost/ckan_default

ckan.datastore.write_url = postgresql://ckan_default:pass@localhost/datastore_default
ckan.datastore.read_url = postgresql://datastore_default:pass@localhost/datastore_default

ckan.site_url = http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

and

```
ckan.plugins = datastore
```

So to test the set up I tried:

```
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=_table_metadata"
```

I get the following output:

"Bad request - Action name not known: datastore_search"

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I solved the problem. In my ckan ckan config file I had ckan.plugins=datastore and ckan.plugins=datapusher. Because of this datastore was not installed. By summaring that to ckan.plugins=datastore datapusher solved this issue.

Comment: Feel free to mark as answered then:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. In my ckan config file I had `ckan.plugins=datastore` and `ckan.plugins=datapusher`. Because of this datastore was not installed. By summaring that to `ckan.plugins=datastore datapusher` solved this issue.